# Objective-C sqlite adding query parameter inside of LIKE clause

Tags: objective-c, c, sqlite, sql-like

I am using `sqlite` in Objective-C via the C API.  One of the intended features of my app is that the user can search for a person name and with each new character they enter, an SQL query using `LIKE` is executed to find all people whose names qualify as a match.  The issue I am running into is parameterizing the match inside the LIKE, without the question mark being interpreted literally.  That is, I believe the app at present is looking for people's names that include `?` in them (which is nobody).

My code looks like this:

```
const char *sql = "SELECT rowid, name, email FROM person WHERE name LIKE '%?%'";
sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Problem preparing getFilteredPeopleStubs statement.");
}
if(sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, 1, [searchText UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Problem binding search text param.");
}
```

Basically, `searchText` is where I *want* the name to be coming from, but at the moment I believe it is just searching for people whose name contains `?`, because of the single quotations in `'%?%'`.  Is there a solution to this problem that still lets me use a parameterized query (protection against SQL injection) and achieves what I am after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `%` characters into `searchText`, like (excuse the pun) this:

```
const char *sql = "SELECT rowid, name, email FROM person WHERE name LIKE ?";
sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Problem preparing getFilteredPeopleStubs statement.");
}
NSString *bindParam = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", searchText];
if(sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, 1, [bindParam UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Problem binding search text param.");
}
```