# SQLite and Objective C - WHERE LIKE Statement Error

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to write a query that involves a WHERE LIKE statement, however I'm running into the following issue....

When I write the query like:

```
"SELECT * FROM db WHERE name LIKE \"%%@%%\""
```

It gets interpreted as:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE name LIKE "(null)"
```

When I query the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM db WHERE name LIKE \"%%%@%%\""
```

It gets interpreted as:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE name LIKE "0x0p+0pple"
```

This:

```
[@"SELECT * FROM db WHERE name LIKE \"%" stringByAppendingString:name] stringByAppendingString:@"%\""]
```

Is interpreted as:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE name LIKE "0x0p+0pple"
```

Is there a way to correct or work around this?

Comment: What is prompting you to write `LIKE \"%%@%\""`?  That looks like a very strange `LIKE` clause to me.

Comment: I had seen these posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357689/objective-c-sqlite-adding-query-parameter-inside-of-like-clause) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357689/objective-c-sqlite-adding-query-parameter-inside-of-like-clause?rq=1) and [3](https://www.innerexception.com/2008/10/using-like-statement-in-sqlite-3-from.html) doing so, I hoped it would help haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a string format, it needs to be:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM db WHERE name LIKE '%%%@%%'", someValue];
```

The first two `%%` become a single `%`. The `%@` gets replaced with whatever string is in `someValue`. And the final two `%%` become a single `%`.

`query` ends up being:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE db LIKE '%apple%'
```

assuming `someValue` is the string `@"apple"`.

On a side note, it's best to avoid using `SELECT * FROM` if you are using the various `sqlite3_column_xxx` functions and specific index numbers because you can't be sure the order of the returned columns matches your code. It's safer and clearer to explicitly list the columns you want from the query.

Comment: That makes perfect sense - thank you so much! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Doi! 
This:

```
[@"SELECT * FROM db WHERE name LIKE \"%%" stringByAppendingString:name] stringByAppendingString:@"%%\""]
```

Is interpreted as:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE db LIKE "%apple%"
```

Which is ACTUALLY what I'm looking for (hadn't realize that at first), this work around just feels a bit... unnecessarily lengthy.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.Its gonna work.

```
  NSString *yourSqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from yourTableName where name LIKE '%%%@%%'",name];
```

Comment: This provides the same information as my answer. Please don't post duplicate answers. You should either delete this answer or edit it to provide relevant helpful information not found in other answers.